# Dual boot with2 SSDs, where do I install the bootloader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader

I'm setting up a dual boot system on a brand new Windows 10 gaming laptop. It has 2 x 500GB SSDs (C: & D:), so I'll be installing Ubuntu on drive D:, which is empty.

Where should I install the bootloader? My first impulse was simply `/sda`, but upon closer inspection, the drive has a 300MB EFI partition. Should I install it there? Will grub detect both Windows 10 and Ubuntu even if they're on separate hard drives?

Comment: It should detect both.  I would use the 'try ubuntu' first and make sure all hardware is detected/working in ubuntu, especially if hardware is brand new on the market.  Make sure nothing is on second drive and make sure you absolutely know which drive ubuntu is installing on.

Comment: Do you have two drives or just two partitions. Microsoft has always confused the issue. A "D:" drive could be a second partition on sda or sda2 or first partition on second drive or sdb1. With Linux drive are clearly separate like sda, sdb, sdc and partitions are numbered within drive like sda1, sda2, etc. With UEFI installs Ubuntu's Ubiquity only installs to first ESP. Bug filed years ago, not critical for internal drives, but some want boot loader on second drive & important to have on external drive. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: It's indeed two separate disks (sda & sdb), not partitions within the same disk. /sda has 3 partitions: EFI, Windows Recovery, and the Windows partition

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub to ESP on first drive, usually sda or first NVMe drive. It should share the ESP, and will not normally overwrite ESP or Windows entries unless you say to reformat partition during install. I like to have ESP on sdb drive, but not normally used. I use it for backup and could reconfigure for boot if first drive failed. Grub can be installed to sdb, and other distributions will let you choose where to install grub.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sda is an acceptable location for the boot loader.

Comment: /sda1 is Windows' EFI partition...so would you advise specifying /sda1, or just /sda?

Comment: /dev/sda  , not /dev/sda1 , so if you remove Windows later, the boot loader survives.

Comment: sda1 is Windows' EFI partition. Windows is actually on sda3 (sda2 is "Windows Recovery). But I'll go for plain sda and let the installer figure it out, thanks!

Comment: Just make sure which drive is which.  Do not think Windows is on sda, make sure Windows is on sda(or sdb whichever one), and install Ubuntu on the other one.  Boot loader goes on sda if that has the EFI partition.

Comment: @crip859 "/sda1 is Windows' EFI partition" OP's 1st comment to this answer.

Comment: @K7AAY Ubuntu does have a habit of changing drive letters sometimes, not often but it does happen once in a blue moon after rebooting if more than one drive.

Comment: Both of the live sessions I've tried (KDE Neon & Kubuntu) fail to recognize my hard drives. Looks like I have some research and tinkering to do BEFORE I even get to the bootloader location "dilemma"

Comment: Basic. So far I've disabled Windows' fast boot, to no avail. Might try disabling secure boot from the BIOS and checking whether it's in AHCI mode

Comment: AHCI? Yes, do try that.

Answer (score 0):

On a system with multiple drives and OS's, the user can preserve the original bootloader by installing GRUB 2 on another drive. Let the Ubuntu installer install grub on the same drive that is selected to install Ubuntu. The Ubuntu installer will install the GRUB 2 files in the appropriate locations at the beginning of sdb which is identified in Windows as D: drive. If you select the option to *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10* in the *Installation type* screen, the Ubuntu installer will put an entry to boot Windows 10 in the grub menu when it installs grub.

When the computer is started it will look for the bootloader in the disk that is selected as the first disk in the boot priority of the UEFI setup utility.

[image]